# iOS: can ccTouchesBegan contain more than one touch?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, touch, touch-event

I am wondering if the NSSet touches in ccTouchesBegan can contain more than one touch.
I did some testing and the touches count is always 1.

Anyone can confirm this? Why would there be a set if there is only one touch?

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     NSSet *set = [event allTouches];

     if (set.count == 1) { //first touch

     }
     if (set.count == 2) { //second touch
     } //etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go buddy .

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch =[[[event allTouches] allObjects] lastObject];

    //NSLog(@"touchesBegan ...");

    switch ([touch tapCount]) 
    {
        case 1:
            [self performSelector:@selector(oneTap) withObject:nil afterDelay:.5];
            break;

        case 2:
            [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(oneTap) object:nil];
            [self performSelector:@selector(twoTaps) withObject:nil afterDelay:.5];
            break;

        case 3:
            [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(twoTaps) object:nil];
            [self performSelector:@selector(threeTaps) withObject:nil afterDelay:.5];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

};



- (IBAction)oneTap
{
    NSLog(@"oneTap ...");


}
- (IBAction)twoTaps
{
    NSLog(@"twoTaps ...");


}

- (IBAction)threeTaps
{
    NSLog(@"threeTaps ...");

}
```